# Multi-threading: Value and Reference types

Tags: c#, multithreading

I just want to confirm my understanding about multi-threading:

- Reference types initialized on the heap **can** be shared between threads
- Value types initialized on the stack **cannot** be shared between threads
- However, value types initialized in an object on the heap **can** be shared between threads.

Comment: Obligatory reference: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx

Comment: Why would *where* types are initialized affect their sharability across threads?

Comment: @Robert Harvey: If a local variable is initialized within a method, it's destroyed as soon as the method `return`. That's my understanding. On the other hand, an object's field member of a class is initialized on the heap along with the object and it continues to survive until its garbage collected.

Comment: That would have been nice to include in your question.  But I see that as merely a scoping problem. The stack is an implementation detail, so it should have no bearing on your code reasoning.  Why would you reasonably expect the lifetime of any object (primitive or not) to extend beyond its local scope?

Comment: This gets a bit more slippery if you consider the case of closures.  In particular, you can use `Task.Run` to execute an anonymous method that closes over a local variable.  The variable is not directly being shared, but it has a similar effect to sharing it.  This comes up more frequently (and implicitly) when you use async/await and pass around what looks like a local variable (but is really an instance member) between thread pool threads as the method resumes at each await.

Comment: @DanBryant And yet the act of closing over a local variable that might otherwise go on the stack will result in it being hoisted to be a field of a reference type, so while a local variable can be accessed from another thread using a closure, a value type on the stack can't be; it will be on the heap.

Comment: @DanBryant Here is [another post by Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types.aspx?Redirected=true) that covers how closures can change storage of local variables to Servy's point.

Answer (score 2):

Reference types exist on the heap.  While you are physically able to share them between threads, they may or may not be designed to be used from different threads.

Value types may or may not exist on the stack.  You are physically able to share value types between threads, but barring `unsafe` code (one could, but almost certainly *shouldn't*, create a pointer to a value type on the stack and expose it to another thread to dereference), the only way you'll be able to do so is for those value types that are on the heap, not on the stack.  As with reference types, they may or may not be designed in such a way as to work properly when accessed from multiple threads.

Comment: This just raises the question "why would a value type ever be on the stack, if its resulting behavior changes?"

Comment: @RobertHarvey The act of being on the stack wouldn't change its behavior, rather being on the stack cannot inherently support the behavior of multithreaded access because the other thread would then potentially be able to access the value type after it's stack frame had expired, thus the only means of exposing a value type to another thread (a closure, as a field of a reference type, a static field) aren't storing the value type on the stack.  The act of closing over the value type, to try to expose it to another thread, will itself hoist it, thus moving it to the heap.

Comment: I think you're thinking about this from the perspective of a C++ programmer.  While your answer is probably technically correct, C# programmers should be looking at this in terms of *scope,* not the way the stack or the heap functions (those are implementation details of the CLR).

Comment: @RobertHarvey The entire question is moot from that perspective.  There isn't even a question when not considering this implementation detail.

Comment: Sure.  It's only relevant if you're trying to punch into the stack, which you've already correctly stated is a monumentally bad idea.

Comment: @RobertHarvey This is one of those questions that almost no one really *needs* to know, but at the same time discussing them can sometimes help improve one's understanding of how the language works.  Yes, you don't need to even know what the stack or the heap are to program in C#, but learning about them *can* help you write better programs, or become a better programmer, hence why I'm not just saying, "you don't need to care, stop asking" here.

Answer (score 1):

Not completely sure, what are you trying to reach but value types and reference types are not connected with threads at all.

However stack is.

Basically what you have written is true.

When you create a value type in some method that his lifetime is only in the block you have declared in. So there is no way of any other thread to access it (there is actually no way to even try to do this with C# code).

When you use a value type as a member of a reference type, your actual just making the size of this reference type bigger, and this value type never ends up on stack, it always ends up in heap so you can use it from different threads.

The first point of your question is obviously true

Also: remember that each thread have it's different stack

Comment: One could, in theory, create a pointer to a value type on the stack in `unsafe` code and then dereference that pointer from another thread.  It would be a terrible, awful, idea, but it *is* possible.

Comment: Yes, using unsafe would make it possible